# 'PolishStack' is not a class template, virtual function ghost error

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm having some problems implementing a class based on a abstract parent class. It's saying PolishStack is an abstract class, even though all virtual functions are coded:

```
In file included from braincalc.cpp:10:
./polstack.h:15:7: error: explicit specialization of non-template class 'PolishStack'
class PolishStack<T> : public AbstractStack<T> {
      ^          ~~~
braincalc.cpp:13:21: error: variable type 'PolishStack<char>' is an abstract class
        PolishStack <char> stk;
                           ^
./abstractstack.h:53:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'isEmpty' in
      'PolishStack'
  virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
```

Here's my class header:

```
#ifndef POLSTACK_H
#define POLSTACK_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "abstractstack.h"


template <typename T>
class PolishStack<T> : public AbstractStack<T> {
        T* data;
        int mMax;
        int mTop;

        public:

                PolishStack();

                bool isEmpty();

                const T& top() const throw (Oops);

                void push(const T& x);

                void pop();

                void clear();

                //my funcs:

                void printStack();


                ~PolishStack();
};

#endif
```

I don't want to give all my code away due to other students cheating, so I'll post the function that the error is complaining about:

```
#include "polstack.h"

//...

template <typename T>
bool PolishStack<T>::isEmpty() {
        if(mTop == 0)
                return true;

    return false;
}

//...
```

Comment: You're missing `const` on your `isEmpty` function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated it should be:

```
template<typename T>
class PolishStack : public AbstractStack<T>
```

> ./abstractstack.h:53:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'isEmpty' in
>         'PolishStack'
>   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

You're missing the `const`:

```
template<typename T>
bool PolishStack<T>::isEmpty() const
//                             ^^^^^
{
        if(mTop == 0)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

**Note:** You should use the `override` keyword to be informed when you try to override a function using a different signature (i.e., you're introducing a new function overload instead of overriding the `virtual` one).

```
template<typename T>
class PolishStack : public AbstractStack<T>
{
public:
    ...

    bool isEmpty() const override;

    ...
};
```

Comment: Good catch. I appreciate it! I didn't know of the override keyword, I'll certainly make note of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
template <typename T>
class PolishStack : public AbstractStack<T>
```

As a side note: Exception specifiers `throw (Oops)` are deprecated.

Comment: That got rid of the first error, but the 2nd still exists. Thanks for the knowledge, I'll have to shout that at my professor during class.

Comment: Then there must be a pure virtual member function in your AbstractStack that is not overidden in your PolishStack. Keep in mind, that the function prototypes must match exactly (except for return types of polymorphic classes), this means that constness and throw specifiers must also match. As the error message states, it seems to be isEmpty(). I assume isEmpty() is const in AbstractStack.

Comment: Just change `bool isEmpty()` to `bool isEmpty() const`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without all the code, but one thing I noticed is that this:

```
class PolishStack<T> : public AbstractStack<T> {
```

should be just:

```
class PolishStack : public AbstractStack<T> {
```

That'll fix the first error for sure and potentially (but maybe not) the second.

Comment: Yeah, the 2nd one still persists.